# What type of wire should I use to repair a toaster oven?

Tags: wiring, repair, replacement, oven

The connector from one of the leads from my toaster oven's power supply to the top heating element broke off.  The wire is too short to just add a new connector, so I need to replace the wire.

The wire was different than others I had seen as it had a knit, fabric-like insulation rather than rubber or silicone.

What kind of wire can I use to replace the broken one, and where can I buy it?  Or, are temperatures in the side of the oven, where the wiring and control circuits live not that high and regular lead wire will work?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about repairing a small appliance. Please see the [help/on-topic] for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That "knit, fabric-like insulation" indicates high temperature wire. [Amazon sells it](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001ALK97C), or if you're foolish like me, you can salvage pieces from old, burnt out [electric drip-style coffee makers](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=0qW&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&biw=1220&bih=568&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=electric%20drip-style%20coffee%20maker&oq=electric%20drip-style%20coffee%20maker&gs_l=img.3...18240.25486.0.26690.11.11.0.0.0.0.679.4826.0j1j1j3j3j3.11.0....0...1c.1.32.img..11.0.0.o0clE8zJiFY).

Comment: It does look very similar to the "high temperature wire" in the Amazon link you specified.  +1 for the tip on salvaging from other old appliances with heating elements.  The wire isn't that expensive, but not worth buying a whole role as I only need a few inches.